# Can't drag and drop any link <a href> to the <input type="text"> if some link has been already pasted to the <input> before

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

It is impossible to paste any link `<a href="#">Link for Drag and Drop</a>` to the `<input type="text"/>` in Chrome by default HTML5 drag and drop, if some link has been already dragged and dropped to the input.

It is reproducable on StackOverflow site as well. Try to drag and drop 'stackoverflow' link to "Search..." input, it works correctly at first. Try again and during dragging over the `<input>` Chrome changes cursor to 'not allowed' [image: cursor icon]

As workaround you can click anywhere before second dragging and now it is possible to paste the link to the same input.

It works without issues for Firefox, IE,Edge, but not for Chrome.

Second attempt to drag and drop the link for Chrome:
[image]

Second completed attempt to drag and drop the link for Firefox:
[image]

Could someone explain this behavior of drag and drop functionality for Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of this behavior for Chrome.
**When you finished drag and drop opearation succesfully, the text of the link which is pasted to the input is still selected even though you can't see this on the screen.** And it is true only for Chrome. All other browesers remove the selection from the target `<input>`/`<textarea>`  after finishing of drag'n drop.

As result you can't finish drag'n drop over selected text, but you can remove selection before next dragging by JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/Klyuch/98tLcxhw/13/